# Install MySQL with XAMPP

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have installed **Apache** through **XAMPP**. Now, I also want to install **MySQL**. But, when I re-run the XAMPP installer, it prompts the error: `The folder does already exist`.

How do I re-run the XAMPP installer?

Comment: What type of system are you working on?

Comment: Rename your old xampp folder and then reinstall. You can then transfer the htdocs folder and the mysql database files if you need them .